# Is PHP's file_get_contents secure for calling third-party APIs?

Tags: php, api, security

I need to call a third-party API using PHP (`file_get_contents`), decode the json response (`json_decode`), and insert the result on a web page.

I wanted to verify that none of these steps would allow a compromised API server to execute arbitrary code on my server.

For this qustion, it's ok if it returns malicious HTML/JS - my question is strictly about executing arbitrary PHP code or system commands on server side.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Here's a code sample.

```
<?php

$API_URL = 'https://HARDCODED.URL/SOMETHING';

$response = file_get_contents($API_URL);
$content = json_decode($response);

$server_address = $content->{'server_address'};

echo $server_address;

?>
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with what methods are safe against poison null byte or null byte injection so I would recommend double checking it against this. Essentially if it is susceptible an attacker could retrieve other files. Example using the method you've describer here http://www.madirish.net/401

Comment: It would be best if you included your full code example, but based on your description there would not be any code execution on your server.

Comment: @cmorrissey Just added one. Thanks.

Comment: @Dane In my case, the API url is hardcoded, so I believe that wouldn't be a problem, right? I just added an example to the question. Thank you.

Comment: As long as you do not do `eval($response);` then you should be good. or blindly write something like `file_put_contents($content->{'filename'}, $content->{'data'});` then you should be good.

Comment: @GabrielBianconi if the api url isn't going to be changed depending on user input then you're fine against this.

Comment: For that example its not executing anything but I would change this line to `$server_address = $content->server_address;` since the name of the variable is knowen you don't need the `{` `}`

Comment: Side-note: if you don't want to work with objects due to the curly-bracket syntax then try `json_decode($response, TRUE);` and it will provide an associative array that you can access like this `$content['server_address']`

Comment: @Dane The API url is always the same. Thank you.

Comment: @GabrielBianconi don't forget to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);` or else someone can intercept your data and modify what you receive.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'm not very familiar with PHP so this might be wrong, but I'm not using curl (unless it's used behind the scenes by `file_get_contents`)? Otherwise, how should I use that?

Comment: @GabrielBianconi Whoops! I forgot that you are using `file_get_contents()`. I can post an answer if you would like.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That's be great, thanks!

Comment: Your example is vulnerable to XSS, assuming the consumer of your web page is a browser.

Comment: @Greg "For this qustion, it's ok if it returns malicious HTML/JS". English is not my first language but I think OP is OK with the fact which you have re-iterated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per request by OP:

**How to convert `file_get_contents()` to a curl request:**

```
<?php

// init the CURL
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // return response as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://HARDCODED.URL/SOMETHING'); // the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE); // verify SSL info

// You MIGHT need this step or else the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER will cause issues
//
// Download https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and save as cacert.pem
//
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/path/to/cacert.pem');
//
// I say MIGHT because your webhost might have already set CURLOPT_CAINFO in the php.ini

// Get JSON
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Basic error handling
if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) === 200)
{
    $content = json_decode($result, TRUE);
}
else
{
    echo 'Something went wrong :( please try again later.';
}

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a client like [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle).
Especially if you don't have experience with accessing external services.

Comment: I just updated the question with a code sample. My case is very simple: basically retrieving a JSON file. Adding a client like that, for such a simple case, would probably make it potentially less secure (plus it's too much overhead) - or am I mistaken? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that using an abstraction layer such as Guzzle is going to provide any benefits to OP especially if OP isn't ready to look under the hood and understand Guzzle. OP is trying to figure out the best PHP practice and Guzzle will only cast a fog as to how PHP does things. The only time I've ever recommended an abstraction layer is for sending emails with PHPMailer because attachments and HTML emails are a very challenging subject. No downvote; just my two cents :)

Comment: Thanks for more detailed info.
If you want to use multiple API endpoints and handle data in a safe and proper way, guzzle will help a lot. I can't agree that's too much overhead, but read the latter part.

@MonkeyZeus is right, that it won't help you understand some of conventions and how to handle basic things like that.